Flutter no muestra correctamente el icono de notificaciones PUSH en android
Mi aplicación móvil android recibe notificaciones push desde firebase. Flutter las recibe correctamente en todos los estados de la aplicación, pero cuando la app está en segundo plano o cerrada, el icono que muestra la push es el icono definido en AndroidManifest.xml
...

<application
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:allowBackup="false"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
...


y no el definido en el mismo archivo para las notificaciones de firebase
...

 <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
     android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher_notification" />
...


Así mismo, indico en el respectivo código Flutter el icono
...

Future initialize() async {
    final NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

    final androidInit =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher_notification');

    final iosInit = IOSInitializationSettings();

    final initSetting = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInit,
      iOS: iosInit,
    );
...


El icono que uso es blanco con fondo transparente, el de la aplicación, sin embargo, es a color y con fondo circular.
He probado a incluir el icono tanto en las carpetas mipmap y drawable, con sus respectivas diferentes carpetas para diferentes dimensiones y sigue apareciendo el icono por defecto asignado para la aplicación.
